# Pyspark. Create column based on multiple columns and by replacing values from dictionary

Tags: pyspark

For example I have a df that look like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP982.png)

And I found a way to create a new column based on values in another column. Now I need to create a column based on all (actually there are 11 of them) columns. Such that, if value from the first column match the key in dictionary, put the value from dictionary  in a new column "Description". If value does not match, go to and check another column etc.
Here is my code

```
def replacement(val, my_dict):
    for k,v in my_dict.items():
        val=val.replace(k,v)
    return val
    
my_dict = {'James':'some_detail','Rose':'other_details', 'M';'different_details'}

replacing = udf(lambda x: replacement(x,my_dict))

new_df = df.withColumn("Description", replacing(col"firstname")))
```

How to change the code?  `replacing` takes only one column, how can it accepts many columns?  Can someone suggest?

EDIT:I need only one column to be created, only "Description". And if "James" was found in my_dict return "some detail" and put it in "Description" column. Do not check the rest of the row, do not check lastname (Smith) gender (M) and salary(8000); go to another row "Anna"

Example of the end df: Note that there is no `0` in a dict, so value is taken from second column. There is no `Robert or Williams` in dict, but we have `M` key-value pair, so we tae value from this pair.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MrR4.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
data2 = [("James","Smith","M",8000),
    ("Michael","Rose","M",7000),
    ("Robert","Williams","M",6000),
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
    
my_dict = {'James':'some_detail','Michael':'trust','Rose':'other_details', 'M':'different_details'}

df2 = df.withColumn("Description",reduce(lambda c, k: c.when(F.col('firstname').rlike(rf"\b{k}\b"), my_dict[k]).when(F.col('lastname').rlike(rf"\b{k}\b"), my_dict[k]).when(F.col('gender').rlike(rf"\b{k}\b"), my_dict[k]).when(F.col('salary').rlike(rf"\b{k}\b"), my_dict[k]), my_dict.keys(),F))
display(df2)
```

[image]

Comment: I need only one column to be created, only "Description". And if "James" was found in my_dict retyrn "some detail" and put it in "Description" column. Do not check the rest of the row, do not check lastname (Smith) gender (M) and salary(8000); go to another row

Comment: can you add a sample required output as part your question?

Comment: I edited the original post and added a pic. Please check

Comment: Hi @good_day have edited my answer check now, if it works accept and upvote the thanks!

Comment: Thank you, Ajaykumar for your help but It is not working the way it should. It must behave like this: if "James" was found in my_dict return "some detail" and put it in "Description" column. Do not check the rest of the row, do not check lastname (Smith) gender (M) and salary(8000); go to another row. And your solution can skip Michel and go to Rose and replace Rose even if Michael exists in the dict

Comment: no just now i tried adding Michael in the dict its working as expected. are you using my code? i have made the change for dict in my answer. just copy my code and execute it should work.

Comment: add Michael to dict after Rose and you will see. Then it matches Rose instead of Michael, even though we have Michael